# rails simple ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i have a problem with ajax request:

in my app i am trying to configure a simple rank system, and i set it up, but whan i click on rank button - i reload the page and rank is refreshed.

Help my realize that in ajax:

i done that:

in `posts/show.html.erb` i have that:

```
    <div id='vote_update'>
      <%= render 'vote/update' %>
    </div>
```

in `vote/_update.html.erb` i have :

```
<% if can? :update, Vote %>
    <%= form_for([@post, @post.vote], remote: true) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit "vote" %>
```

in `vote/update.js.erb` i have:

```
$('#vote_update').html("<%= j render('vote/update') %>");
```

and in vote_controller.rb i have:

```
  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    vote = post.vote
...
    respond_to do |format|
        if vote.save
          format.html { 
            redirect_to post_path(post),
            :notice => "You vote counted!"
          }
          format.js
        end
    end
end
```

if i remove romete: true - everything goes right ( page is reload, i saw (:notice) "You vote counted!" and rating is updated, but if i put remote: true back, i saw nothing ( some mistakes in firebug console ) - but when i reload page - ratign is updated, nd i saw norml result - i think i madesome mistakes in redirecting or i dont know

help please

Comment: your ajax code will come in format.js block. where you can update the html where you are showing the rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ajax code will come in format.js block. where you can update the html where you are showing the rank.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean, you described what I was trying to do in the question - when i click in submit btn, i send a request to vote/update.js.erb and there i trying update my $('#vote_update') - div block, but in my question i have some mistake and i don't know where

Comment: Oops, Dimitry I missed that part, Inside your update.js.erb you can have js to updat rank and also show flash message

Comment: No you were right, I render - but render not what I needed =) thanks =))

Answer (score 0):

change

```
respond_to do |format|
    if vote.save
      format.html { 
        redirect_to post_path(post),
        :notice => "You vote counted!"
      }
      format.js
    end
end
```

to
       if vote.save
    respond_to do |format|

```
      format.html { 
        redirect_to post_path(post),
        :notice => "You vote counted!"
      }
      format.js
    end
end
```

Not sure though